# Where does the brooch that Luna gives Usagi come from if she wasn't originally a Sailor Scout?

Tags: sailor-moon

Using this as a reference [tumblr page](https://silvermoon424.tumblr.com/post/97346293538/sailor-venus-the-leader) where I read from the images of the manga, that Sailor Moon never existed until the reincarnation of Princess Serenity as Usagi. Luna turned her into a Sailor Scout to protect her real identity as Princess from the enemies.

So, then where did the brooch come from? Is this specified in any of the manga books?

Comment: You've got the answer already. If they did that deliberately to protect her identity, it means that the brooch was specifically made during that incarnation for that specific purpose.